# How to convert data to JSON format, using SBJSON iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, json, iphone-sdk-4.3

I want to convert the given data to JSON format ... please help me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
{
    data =     (
        {
            id = 1307983297;
            name = "Aafaaq Mehdi";
        },
        {
            id = 1350886273;
            name = "Shah Asad";
        },
        {
            id = 1636300537;
            name = "Imran Baig";
        },
        {
            id = 1640049813;
            name = "Vinod Gowda";
        }
    );
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:appDelegate.friendList];
 results= (NSArray *)[dict valueForKey:@"data"];
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 // loop over all the results objects and print their names
        int ndx;

        for (ndx = 0; ndx < results.count; ndx++) 
        {
            [arr addObject:(NSDictionary *)[results objectAtIndex:ndx]];
        }
        FriendListModel *obj;    
        for (int x=0; x<[arr count]; x++) 
        {
            obj = [[[FriendListModel alloc] initWithjsonResultDictionary:[arr objectAtIndex:x]] autorelease];
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:obj];
NSMutableArray *facebookJSON = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

            for (obj in arr) {
NSDictionary *syedDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj.friendId,@"id", obj.friendName, @"name", nil];
NSString *facebookJSONFormat = [syedDict JSONRepresentation];
[facebookJSON addObject:facebookJSONFormat];
 }
NSString *myArrayString = [facebookJSON description];

        NSString *braceInArr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", myArrayString];
[self setFormDataRequest:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]];
            [formDataRequest setDelegate:self];
[formDataRequest setPostValue:braceInArr forKey:@"friend_list"];
[formDataRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
        [formDataRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];

        [formDataRequest startAsynchronous];
```

I got the output in this format:-

```
[(
    "{\"id\":\"1307983297\",\"name\":\"No Man\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"1350886273\",\"name\":\"Shah Asad\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"1636300537\",\"name\":\"Imran Baig\"}",
    "{\"id\":\"1640049813\",\"name\":\"Vinod Gowda\"}"
)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id": 1307983297,
            "name": "Aafaaq Mehdi"
        },
        {
            "id": 1350886273,
            "name": "Shah Asad"
        },
        {
            "id": 1636300537,
            "name": "Imran Baig"
        },
        {
            "id": 1640049813,
            "name": "Vinod Gowda"
        }
    ]
}
```

That's your dad in JSON format... as for converting it, do you have a parser for the original format?

Comment: this is the format, I got from facebook- friend list. now I wanna send this to our Server in JSON format. My question is - How to change this in JSON format using objective C. I'll update my question.. what I have done till now?